# Getting “java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out ,when connecting to mongo db hosted on aws EC2

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have tried connect via putty it worked fine. I m not getting how add the pem file path and user name to login to Mongo shell via java

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.xx-xxxx-1.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com" , 27017 );
 DB db = mongoClient.getDB("userDB");

```
       Set<String> tables = db.getCollectionNames();
        for(String coll : tables){
        System.out.println(coll);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This more seems to be a firewall issue to me. Can you please check whether have you enabled port 27017 in the security group that you are using.

AWS Security group configuration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules

If the port is enabled on security groups but still a problem then, check MongoDB server binding.

MongoDB sometimes defaults the binding address to 127.0.0.1, which will disable public IP or DNS communication to the server.

Please refer this to find and change IPBind configuration. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

If the bind defaults to 127.0.0.1 then, change it to 0.0.0.0 so that, it will start listening to all the IP addresses.

Comment: thanks Matrix for your reply,Do you have any sample java code as i tried your suggestion but still facing same issue